# How to define a command to switch to the current candidate buffer in Ido?

Tags: buffers, minibuffer, commands, ido

I'm trying to write a command that I would call while using `ido-switch-buffer` or `ido-kill-buffer` to open the current candidate in another window. Ideally it would be able to open virtual buffers as well.

One thing it seems I've got right is that I need to bind it in `ido-buffer-completion-map`:

```lisp
(define-key ido-buffer-completion-map "\C-n" #'ido-visit-buffer-other-window)
```

But I can't make a function that works. I've given up at

```lisp
(defun ido-visit-buffer-other-window (candidate)
  "Visit the buffer at the head of ‘ido-matches’ in its window or
in a new one if no one is displaying it."
  (interactive (list (car ido-matches)))
  (let ((buffer (or (get-buffer candidate)
                    ;; Check for a virtual buffer reference.
                    (find-file-noselect (cdr (assoc candidate ido-virtual-buffers))))))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window buffer)))
```

Whatever I do the Ido prompt remains lingering in the minibuffer. Every way of getting out of the minibuffer that I've tried breaks the function:

- `(exit-minibuffer)` or `(ido-exit-minibuffer)` switch to the candidate buffer (in the current window) if I had called `ido-switch-buffer` or they kill it if I had called `ido-kill-buffer`;
- with `(minibuffer-keyboard-quit)` and `(abort-recursive-edit)` (thanks Drew for the tip!) the command does nothing.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does "breaks the function" mean here? Have you tried `(abort-recursive-edit)` instead of `(exit-minibuffer)`? How does Ido normally end its minibuffer interaction - is it with `exit-minibuffer`?

Comment: Hi @Drew :-) see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unfortunately going to have to use two functions: one that does the work and one that exits Ido.

```lisp
(defun ido-visit-buffer-other-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (car ido-matches))
        entry)
    (cond
     ((get-buffer buf)
      (add-to-history 'buffer-name-history buf)
      (ido-visit-buffer buf 'other-window t))
     ((and ido-enable-virtual-buffers
           ido-virtual-buffers
           (setq entry (assoc buf ido-virtual-buffers)))
      (ido-visit-buffer (find-file-noselect (cdr entry)) 'other-window t))
     (t
      (user-error "No match")))))

(defun ido-run-visit-buffer-other-window ()
  (interactive)
  (setq ido-exit 'fallback)
  (setq ido-fallback 'ido-visit-buffer-other-window)
  (exit-minibuffer))
```

Now you can bind `ido-run-visit-buffer-other-window` in `ido-buffer-completion-map` to whatever key sequence you like.